# How can I solve this error with my Spring Jpa application?

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, entity

I am having a problem with a Maven Spring app (I am a very beginner learner!). When I create:

```
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
  return new JpaTransactionManager(getEntityManagerFactory()
    .getObject()); 
}
```

I get this error:

> The method getObject() from the type AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean
> refers to the missing type EntityManagerFactory.

I also have this:

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean getEntityManagerFactory() {
  LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean bean = new 
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
  bean.setDataSource(getDataSource());
  bean.setJpaVendorAdapter(null);
  bean.setPackagesToScan(getClass().getPackage().getName());
  return bean;
}
```

What can I do?
Thank you so much!

I don't know what to do!

Comment: I'm not familiar with the method `.getObject()` on this class, but since you're creating a `PlatformTransactionManager` and `JpaTransactionManager` IS A `PlatformTransactionManager`, then you just need to return it:
 `return new JpaTransactionManager(getEntityManagerFactory();`

Comment: Thank you very much! If I return new JpaTransactionManager(getEntityManagerFactory(); I get this error: The constructor JpaTransactionManager (LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean) is undefined.

Comment: change the  argument to `getEntityManagerFactory().getNativeEntityManagerFactory()`, so it would be `return new JpaTransactionManager(getEntityManagerFactory().getNativeEntityManagerFactory());`